# Aligning Rows with Flex-Box in React-Native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, flexbox

I'm having difficulty aligning elements. I'm trying to align my elements(Past Due) and (current Balance) side-by-side, but instead they are showing one on top of the other. Normally I would use float to solve this issue, but RN doesn't support it. How can I align these two elements to show horizontally?

[image: Current]

[image: Desired]

```
  <View style={styles.header} key={i}>

        <View style={styles.headerthing}>
        <Text style={styles.rowLabelText}>{'Due Today'}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.rowLabelnum} >{accounting.formatMoney(rows.AMOUNT_DUE_NOW_INC_LC)}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.headerthing2}>
        <Text style={styles.rowLabelText}>{'Past Due'}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.rowLabelnum} >{accounting.formatMoney(rows.AMOUNT_DUE_NOW_INC_LC)}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.headerthing3}>
        <Text style={styles.rowLabelText}>{'Current Balance'}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.rowLabelnum} >{accounting.formatMoney(rows.AMOUNT_DUE_NOW_INC_LC)}</Text>
        </View>

     </View>
```

Styles......

```
 header: {
    width: window.width,
    height: window.height * 0.4,

  },


headerthing: {
        alignItems: 'center',
            flex: 1,
  },


   headerthing2: {
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
            flex: 1,    
  },


   headerthing3: {
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
            flex: 1,

  },

  rowLabelnum: {
  fontFamily: 'PT_SANS-WEB-REGULAR',
    fontSize: 30,
  color : '#FFFFFF',
  },

rowLabelText: {
 fontFamily: 'PT_SANS-WEB-BOLD',
    fontSize: 28,
  color : '#FFFFFF',
  },
```

Comment: what's the styling for `header`?

Comment: I just edited my post to include.

Comment: I don't know how you would do it in RN but this is how you'd do it with normal css. that help? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbVbvL

Comment: Could you not wrapthe two current balance & past due under one view and style it with `{{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}` as per  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css is simple, but replace my `grid` class with your class, guess it's `header` in your case..

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
  background: blue; color: white;
}
.headerthing{
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
.headerthing2, .headerthing3{
  flex: 1;
}
.rowLabelnum{
  font-family: 'PT_SANS-WEB-BOLD'; font-size: 30px; color: '#FFFFFF';
}
.rowLabelText{
  font-family: 'PT_SANS-WEB-BOLD'; font-size: 28px; color: '#FFFFFF';
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="headerthing">
    <p class="rowLabelText">Due Today</p>
    <p class="rowLabelnum">$485.66</p>
  </div>
  <div class="headerthing2">
    <p class="rowLabelText">Past Today</p>
    <p class="rowLabelnum">$485.66</p>
  </div>
  <div class="headerthing3">
    <p class="rowLabelText">Current Balance</p>
    <p class="rowLabelnum">$485.66</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is this the selected answer? This is HTML not React Native.

Answer (score 0):

In `react-native`, you control direction using `flexDirection` style property. So you can change to something like

```
    <View style={styles.headerthing}>
    <Text style={styles.rowLabelText}>{'Due Today'}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.rowLabelnum} >{accounting.formatMoney(rows.AMOUNT_DUE_NOW_INC_LC)}</Text>
    </View>

   <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: row}}>
    <View style={styles.headerthing2}>
    <Text style={styles.rowLabelText}>{'Past Due'}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.rowLabelnum} >{accounting.formatMoney(rows.AMOUNT_DUE_NOW_INC_LC)}</Text>
    </View>

    <View style={styles.headerthing3}>
    <Text style={styles.rowLabelText}>{'Current Balance'}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.rowLabelnum} >{accounting.formatMoney(rows.AMOUNT_DUE_NOW_INC_LC)}</Text>
    </View>
   </View>
 </View>
```